# Keyboard layout hotkeys

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, 19.04

After installing Ubuntu 19.04 I can't set the hotkey to change the keyboard layout to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. I'm opening to **Settings** -> **Devices** -> **Keyboard** searching for *Input and trying* to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> but nothing is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Install gnome-tweaks and look for keyboard and mouse -- additional layout options..

Comment: Or.. run the command and copy the output `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` then run the command to set Alt+Shift for changing the layout `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['grp:alt_shift_toggle']"`

Comment: gnome-tweaks solved my problem. Thank you so much.